# Spark Scala -difference between current date and max(day)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, date-difference

Need to calculate the difference between two dates. The question is

```
Currentdate - max(day_id)
```

"Currentdate" is of simple date format - `yyyyMMdd`

"day_id" is of string format and its value is `yyyy-mm-dd`.

I have a dataframe which converted the date(string format) to date format (yyyy-mm-dd)

```
df1 = to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(day_id, 'yyyy-MM-dd')))
```

Normally, for finding the max(day_id), I would do

`def daySince (columnName: String): Column = {
    max(col(columnName))`

I cannot figure out how to do the difference between

```
Currentdate - max(day_id)
```

Comment: there is a [current_date inbuilt funtion](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#current_date--)

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example ?

Comment: I have tried answering below if it meets your needs

Answer (score 2):

Given *input dataframe with schema* as

```
+---+----------+
|id |day_id    |
+---+----------+
|id1|2017-11-21|
|id1|2018-01-21|
|id2|2017-12-21|
+---+----------+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- day_id: string (nullable = true)
```

you can use `current_date()` and `datediff()` *inbuilt functions* to meet your requirement as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("diff", datediff(current_date(), to_date(col("day_id"), "yyyy-MM-dd")))
```

which should give you

```
+---+----------+----+
|id |day_id    |diff|
+---+----------+----+
|id1|2017-11-21|167 |
|id1|2018-01-21|106 |
|id2|2017-12-21|137 |
+---+----------+----+
```